# How to change image through click - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a toolbar that has 5 table cells. The first cell looks clear, and the other 4 have a shade over them. I want to make it so that clicking on the table cell will also change the image so that the shade will also change in respect to the current table cell that is selected.

```
<script src="../../jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"> 

    $('table.stories-preview td').click((function () {
    var last_image = null;

    return function () {
        if (last_image) {
            $('table.stories-preview .selected').attr('src', last_image).removeClass('selected');
        }

        var $clicked_image = $('img', this);
        last_image = $clicked_image.attr('src');
        $clicked_image.attr('src', 'http://i1251.photobucket.com/albums/hh544/kochb/th_checklist_on.png').addClass('selected');
    }
})());


     $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fade").css("display", "none");

    $(".fade").fadeIn(500);



    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
}); 

    $(document).ready(function() {

     $('.preview').hide();

  $('#link_1').click(function(){ 
      $('#latest_story_preview1').hide();
       $('#latest_story_preview2').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview3').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview4').hide();
      $('#latest_story_main').fadeIn(800);
  });   

  $('#link_2').click(function(){ 
      $('#latest_story_main').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview2').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview3').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview4').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview1').fadeIn(800);
  });

  $('#link_3').click(function(){ 
      $('#latest_story_main').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview1').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview3').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview4').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview2').fadeIn(800);
  });

    $('#link_4').click(function(){ 
      $('#latest_story_main').hide();
       $('#latest_story_preview1').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview2').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview4').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview3').fadeIn(800);
  });
    $('#link_5').click(function(){ 
      $('#latest_story_main').hide();
       $('#latest_story_preview1').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview2').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview3').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview4').fadeIn(800);
  });





    });

</script>




    <table class="stories-preview" width="330" height="598" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a id="link_1" href="#"> <img src="../../Images/N&EImages/images-con-1/Article-Nav-Bar1_01.gif" width="330" height="114" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a id="link_2" href="#"> <img src="../../Images/N&EImages/images-con-1/Article-Nav-Bar1_02.gif" width="330" height="109" alt=""> </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <a id="link_3" href="#"> <img src="../../Images/N&EImages/images-con-1/Article-Nav-Bar1_03.gif" width="330" height="132" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a id="link_4" href="#"><img src="../../Images/N&EImages/images-con-1/Article-Nav-Bar1_04.gif" width="330" height="124" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a id="link_5" href="#"><img src="../../Images/N&EImages/images-con-1/Article-Nav-Bar1_05.gif" width="330" height="119" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm trying to replace the image, right now I have jquery code that allows me to replace the div in respect to the selection from the table. But I would also like to change the table itself, so the table cell looks different when the div is selected in correspondance with that table cell.

Comment: The above code contains extraneous information.  Please trim it down to only the relevant code, and update it with any changes that you make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the general question, you can use javascript and CSS to highlight an individual cell on click.  I threw together a [JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mqaL7/); you can adapt that for your purposes.

And here's [a version that can swap out images](http://jsfiddle.net/mqaL7/3/) for you.

Comment: I tried applying it to my table, but I couldn't get it to work. It would interfere with my anchor tags. How do I get around this?

Comment: Define interfere.  What kind of unexpected complication happened?

Comment: Ok, the code I wrote shouldn't cause that, do you have custom modifications?  You need to keep us updated with the relevant code so we can help you.

Comment: The most recent code is above, but I think that your code is only going to work with just text table cells, my table cells are images.

Comment: OK, I didn't see your message from earlier, I will trim it down. My apologies

Comment: That looks like the original code.  Where's your attempt at implementing this?  I've also included an example that changes out images, for your reference.

Comment: I just applied it to my page, but I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: Your selector is wrong, `table.stories-preview` should be `table#stories-preview` since stories-preview is an id.  Easy mistake to make =)